# Read a .txt file and output him in <p> HTML (with JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried a lot of possibilities, but most of them **don't work or require modules**, but I don't know how to do this in **vanilla javascript**.. **I really need some help**.. Thanks. (Sorry for my bad English, I'm french)

My script : (don't really work, just read)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fso, ts, s;
  fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  f1 = fso.OpenTextFile("pub.txt", 1);
  s = ts.ReadLine();
</script>
```

Comment: To preview the file in client side use HTML5 [`FileReader API`](https://javascript.info/file#filereader), but the recommended way is to use a server side API to input a file and render its output as the response of the API

Comment: Kindly share us the code

Comment: I will share my test code but i dont really know if its working*

Comment: My script is just for reading and i dont really know what to do with it 

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var fso, ts,s;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f1 = fso.OpenTextFile("pub.txt", 1);
s = ts.ReadLine();

</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out!

```html
<input type="file" onchange="readFile(this)" />

<script>
  function readFile(input) {
    let file = input.files[0];

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsText(file);

    reader.onload = function () {
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `<p>${reader.result}</p>`;
    };

    reader.onerror = function () {
      console.log(reader.error);
    };
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading a text file:

```
fetch('file.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  // outputs the content of the text file
```

Using Jquery:

```
$("#div7").load("ajax.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: a working example here
https://codepen.io/engeslamadell/pen/WNrVPeG

did you tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//this is the input with type file
    document.getElementById('inputfile') 
        .addEventListener('change', function() { 
          
        var fr=new FileReader(); 
        fr.onload=function(){ 
            document.getElementById('output') 
                    .textContent=fr.result; 
        } 
          
        fr.readAsText(this.files[0]); 
    }) 
</script>
```

you also have these `FileReader` methods
`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`: Reads the contents of the specified input file. The result attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file’s data.
`FileReader.readAsBinaryString()`: Reads the contents of the specified input file. The result attribute contains the raw binary data from the file as a string.
`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`: Reads the contents of the specified input file. The result attribute contains a URL representing the file’s data.
`FileReader.readAsText()`: Reads the contents of the specified input file. The result attribute contains the contents of the file as a text string. This method can take encoding version as the second argument(if required). The default encoding is UTF-8.

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-a-local-text-file-using-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("input[type='file']").addEventListener("change", function(){
    if(this.files[0]){
      this.files[0].text()
        .then(val => {
          document.querySelector("p").textContent = val;
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<label>Pick One Text File</label><br/>
<input type="file" accept="text/plain" multiple="false"> <br/>

<label>File Will Show up here in the text box</label><br/><br/>
<p></p>
```